# Why doesn't a 'static function argument make something live for the entire program?

Tags: rust

I still don't understand the behavior of `'static`. In the following code, `say_foo` works but `say_bar` does not:

```
fn say_foo(_: &String) -> &str {
    "foo!"
}
fn say_bar(_: &'static String) -> &str {
    "bar!"
}

fn main() {
    let f = "f".to_string();
    let f2 = say_foo(&f); // ok:)
    println!("{}", f2);

    let b = "b".to_string();
    let b2 = say_bar(&b); // error:`b` does not live long enough
    println!("{}", b2);
}
```

Even if I pass `reference` to both functions, the life expectancy of the passed variable is different between `say_foo` and `say_bar`.

In [the chapter about lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html), I found that `'static` is a signal that makes a lifetime of something to live in the entire program.

But this `'static` does not seem to act like that: `b` was released before `b2` (and `f`).

What does `'static` mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake, attempting to dictate the lifetime of a reference, however **lifetimes are descriptive, not prescriptive**.

---

`'static` is the lifetime of all things that live for the entire duration of the program, for example in:

```
const ID: usize = 4;

fn print(i: &'static usize) { println!("{}", i); }

fn main() {
    print(&ID);
}
```

The lifetime of `ID` is `'static` and therefore I can pass `&ID` to a function expecting a `&'static usize`.

If I have a variable of type `usize` in `main`:

```
fn main() {
    let i = 4usize;
    print(&i);
}
```

the compiler will however complain that `i` does not live long enough because `&'static usize` as a parameter type is a *requirement*: it says that ONLY variables which live at least as long as `'static` (which is the longest possible lifetime) will be accepted. And `i`'s lifetime is shorter, so it's rejected.

---

To reiterate: *all things in Rust have an intrinsic lifetime, and the `'a` notation is only a way of **observing it** not a way of **modifying it**.*

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to read more about [lifetime ellision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision). The two functions, with lifetimes made explicit, are defined as follows:

```
fn say_foo<'a>(_: &'a String) -> &'a str {...}

fn say_bar(_: &'static String) -> &'static str {...}
```

Calling `say_bar` on `&b` does not work because `b` does not have a static lifetime. You cannot pass a reference with a shorter lifetime than the one specified. On the other hand, calling `say_foo` works because the lifetime parameter `'a` is resolved to `&b`'s lifetime.