# Difference between "p: &'a i32" and "p: &'static i32" lifetime in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I started learning Rust a few days back.

This is an extract from the famous book *Programming Rust* by Jim Blandy.

For the code

```
fn g<'a>(p: &'a i32) { ... }

let x = 10;
g(&x);
```

The book says

> Rust Choose the smallest possible lifetime for &x, that of the call to g. This meets all constraints: it doesn't outlive x, and encloses the entire call to g. So code must muster.

Q1. What is meant by the smallest possible lifetime for `&x`?

For the code

```
fn f(p: &'static i32) { ... }

let x = 10;
f(&x);
```

Q2. Why does this code fail? According to my understanding, `&'static` is used for static global variables which live for the full program. [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8rhmj8/how_does_static_lifetime_work/)

Comment: Q2 seems to be its own answer: `x` is not a static global variable, so the code fails.

Comment: This looks to me like a duplicate of [Why doesn't a 'static function argument make something live for the entire program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719580/why-doesnt-a-static-function-argument-make-something-live-for-the-entire-progr) Do the answers to that question also answer yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `'static` lifetime is a special concept. It specifies that the variable referenced by this needs to exist for the **entire** lifetime of the program. Using this is a rare case, and requires even rarer precautions to fulfill.

In practice, a `&'static` reference may only happen in two cases:

- A `const` declaration
- A `static` declaration

Both effectively accomplish the same thing, in different ways; the differences aren't important to this question, however. In both cases, the outcome is a variable that is available for the entire lifetime of the program and will not be relocated, thus guaranteeing `&'static` if borrowed.

Now that we've covered this, let's cover both of your questions.

---

> Q1. What is meant by the smallest possible lifetime for &x?

When you define a function as `fn g<'a>(p: &'a i32) { ... }`, you are requiring `p` to be valid for a lifetime `'a`; this lifetime is determined by the compiler so that `'a` is the **smallest possible**. If the reference is never used outside of the function scope, `'a` will be the lifetime of execution of that function, for example. If you use or reference this borrow outside of the function, the lifetime will (evidently) be larger.

The definition of "smallest possible" is simple: the compiler will infer the lifetime based from the time you start that reference, to the last time you use that reference. Dependent borrows also count, and this typically comes back to bite people when dealing with collections.

The reason it is the smallest possible is so that you don't run into crazy situations where you don't have a borrow but it is borrowed anyway; this typically happens when you try to provide your own, incorrect, lifetime hints. There are plenty of cases where it is usually best to let the compiler decide; the other case is `struct` implementations such as the following:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    item: &'a u32
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn compare<'b>(&self, other: &'b u32) {
        ...
    }
}
```

A common fault in situations like this is to describe `other` to the compiler as `'a`, **not** defining the second `'b` lifetime, and thus (accidentally) requiring `other` to be borrowed for the lifetime of the `struct` itself.

---

> Q2. Why does this code fail? According to my understanding, &'static is used for static global variables which live for the full program.

```
let x = 10;
```

This assignment does not have a `'static` lifetime. It has an anonymous lifetime defined as less than `'static`, because it is not **strictly** defined as global. The *only* way to get a `'static` borrow on anything is if that source element is defined as `const` or `static`.

You can convince yourself of this with this snippet ([**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc8e3ac3e112bfb187c0976090f05f73)):

```
fn f(p: &'static i32) {
    println!("{}", p)
}

const FOO:i32 = 3;
static BAR:i32 = 4;

fn main() {
    f(&FOO); // Works
    f(&BAR); // Also works
}
f(&x);
```

Comment: Thanks, @SébastienRenauld for the well-structured answer with examples.
On a side note, will replacing `&'a` with `&'static` in struct Foo of code block 1 work?

Comment: @AdityaArora It is possible ([link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab93d789553ace15cbf31bd847f29712)) but it is *extremely* rare. Due to the requirement for the inner reference to be `&'static`, literally the only thing that will fit in there is `static` or `const` definitions. As `static` definitions do not allow initialization (without `lazy_static`) you're very limited in what you can do with that.

Answer (score 1):

A `'static` lifetime requirement on a reference requires this argument to be declared for the global lifetime of the program, but `x` cannot fulfill this condition as it is declared midway through execution.

To be able to use this, declare x as `const` or `static` so its lifetime will be `'static` and the code will work fine.

Comment: I agree that declaring x as a static or const will solve the problem, But if the lifetime of a variable is smaller than the reference variable mentioned in the function definition, then it should work. `x` lifetime will be shorter than `'static` lifetime.

Is it necessary to have same lifetime for the reference and the referent?

Comment: @AdityaArora you got it the wrong way: input variable lifetime needs to be at least as long as specified in the function declaration.

Comment: @trentcl the code example was added by PitaJ and was not the OP's. The edit should be flagged and rolled back.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Why it couldn't be less than specified in the function declaration? I agree greater will create problems.

Comment: @AdityaArora Added an answer of my own to try to clarify things a bit. Let me know if there's anything not clear; it is a long one, however.

Comment: @AdityaArora 'static is a bit of a special case but think of a lifetime that is specified for both input and output of a function: in this case typically the output is a reference into the input variable: if your input variable was allowed to not exist throughout the given lifetime, the output variable might reference non-existing data even if it does not exceed the lifetime.